# To return a string to a parametrised function and calling the same in action

Tags: function, parameter-passing, hp-uft

I used a function called-Check(x,y),where x is a variable and y is an integer, which is in the function library in UFT.
The scenario:
if argument passed is, say "Hello"and the integer is 2(called in the Action),if the string is found in the application it should return "found" to function Check and the same should be able to reuse. My question is how to reuse the function with parameters if only a string is returned.
eg:if check <> "found" then 
      "do something"
while using this I get a general run error. Please help

Answer (score 1):

QTP uses VBScript as it scripting language wtihin UFT.

In my experience, QTP is picky about usage of Subroutines vs. Functions.  The only functional difference (that I have found) between a sub and a function is whether or not you are trying to read the return value out of it.  If you do, then QTP insists that you must use parentheses around the functions parameters.

IF you want to reuse the value that the function returns, then you could store it's return value in a variable instead of checking it directly.  For example, instead of:

```
if Check("Hello",2) <> "found" then DoSomething()
```

you could do

```
Result = Check("Hello",2)
if Result <> "found" then
 DoSomething(Result)
else
 DoSomethingElse(Result)
End If
```

I hope that helps, your question is kind of vague.

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer as it is the only one, and obviously it solved you problem.